# Spring boot and javax caching

Tags: caching, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app and I am trying to configure javax cache. if I include the enable caching annotation then spring can't find the javax cacheManager defined in the bean below.  If I comment out the caching annotation the bean is found but I get an error that no caching provider was configured.  Any insight would be appreciated.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

@Bean(name = "cacheManager")
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
      CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
      CacheManager cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager();
      Arrays.stream(LookupCache.values()).forEach(e -> cacheManager.createCache(e.getName(), e.cacheConfig(List.class)));
      return cacheManager;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
javax.cache.CacheException: No CachingProviders have been configured
```

This exception means that there is no `CachingProviders` implementation (.jar) on the classpath.

Consider  add a `CachingProvider` implementation to pom.xml file, for example Ehcache:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

`Caching.getCachingProvider()` ([from Ehcache 3.x JSR-107 Provider doc.](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.0/107.html) )

> Retrieves the default CachingProvider implementation from the
>   application’s classpath. This method will work if and only if there is
>   only one JCache implementation jar in the classpath. If there are
>   multiple providers in your classpath then use the fully qualified name
>   org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider to retrieve the Ehcache
>   caching provider. You can do this by using the
>   Caching.getCachingProvider(String) static method instead.